# Get and put a string in Haskell throws error

Tags: haskell, ghc

I found the following Haskell code, but I'm confused:

```hs
main = putStrLn "Enter 1st String:"  
  >> getLine
  >>= \a -> read a
```

1. What do the two "greater than" symbols (`>>`) mean? A new statement?
2. What do the two "greater than" symbols followed by an equal sign (`>>=`) mean?

This Haskell code throws the following error:

```
a.hs:3:13:
No instance for (Read (IO t0)) arising from a use of ‘read’
In the expression: read a
In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘\ a -> read a’
In the expression:
  putStrLn "Enter 1st String:" >> getLine >>= \ a -> read a
```

Comment: What do you want to do, exactly? `read` does not do any I/O, so it can't be chained to a sequence of I/O actions.

Comment: Note that `>>` is *one* operator; Haskell sees the two characters as one name. (Much like `getLine` is one name, not a sequence of separate letters.) Haskell allows you to define new operators; for example, if you wanted to define a function called `**?!`, you can...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) does two greater than symbols mean a new statement?

In this context, yes. In the IO monad, `>>` is a rough equivalent of the `;` in many imperative programming languages.

> 2) what does two greater than symbols followed by equal sign mean?

`x >>= y` is like `x >> y` except it takes the result of `x` and applies to `y`, which has to be a function. Briefly put, `getLine >>= \a -> action` means "read a line, bind that value to variable `a`, and run `action` (which can depend from `a`).

I'd recommend a monad tutorial to fully understand these. You can start with a general tutorial such as [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Your code is more commonly written in `do` notation:

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter 1st String:"  
  a <- getLine
  read a
```

where the last line makes no sense: `read` returns a value but does not do any I/O, so we can not chain that to a sequence of I/O actions. This triggers a compiler error. If you know some imperative programming, think about the pseudocode

```
print("some message");
a = inputLine();
toInteger(a);
```

The last line makes no sense: it converts the string into an integer... and then does not use the result in any way.

Comment: hi chi, thanks for your answer... is the purpose of `do` block to avoid prefixing statement with `>`?

Comment: @MadhavanKumar Yes, do notation is a more convenient notation for `>>` and `>>=`.

Answer (score 2):

About your second question: your `main` is not a valid monadic expression. When specialised to the `IO` monad, the *bind* and *then* operators have type

```
(>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
(>>)  :: IO a ->     IO b    -> IO b
```

If you try to align the types of your `main` expression, you will identify the problem very quickly:

```
putStrLn "Enter 1st String:"  >>  getLine   >>=  \a -> read a

{           IO ()          }    {IO String}      {actual: Read t => String -> t   }

{                  IO String              }      {expected:         String -> IO t}         ???         }
```

The type expected for the second argument of `>>=` is `String -> IO t`, but `read` doesn't return an `IO` value.